# Enforcing common foreign key in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, data-modeling

I have the following interesting data modeling problem.  I am going to use the example of restaurants to illustrate it: Consider the following three entities: `Restaurant`, `Location` and `Offer`.

- A `restaurant` can have many `locations` and a `restaurant` can have many `offers`.

Those relationships are easy to represent: A `Restaurant` table; a `Location` table with a `FK` from the `Restaurant` table; and a `Offer` table with a `FK` from the `Restaurant` table.

The interesting problem comes now:

- An `offer` can only be valid on certain `locations` of a `restaurant`.

The modeling of that restriction seems easy at the beginning: just do an association table with two foreign keys, one from the `Offer` table, and another one from the `Location` table.

The problem with that solution is that it does not restrict me from associating `offers` and `locations` that do not belong to the same restaurant.

How could I model this in a better way that would allow me to enforce that restriction at the database level?

Comment: I'd probably end up making a linking `restaurant_locations` table that stores each location a restaurant can have and then make a foreign key to that table.

Comment: That would mean creating a `restaurant_locations` table for each restaurant, right?

Comment: No, this table would store records with all locations for every restaurant in separate rows. Imagine that table having `id, id_restaurant, id_location` with two latter columns being `FKs` to tables `restaurant` and `location`. This model is considerably good if you allow two restaurants under same location.

Comment: @ConsiderMe Locations is already a table that stores each location a restaurant can have. At least that's how I interpret this model, each location maps to 1 restaurant.

Comment: @popovitsj you may be right, but there was no mention about uniqueness of restaurant locations (like shared spaces under the same postal address). I know this may be a rare case but it still sometimes exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that in your current model Location has 1 restaurant and Offer has 1 Restaurant.

You can solve your problem by making a compound key on Offer: (Restaurant_ID, Offer_ID) and use this key as a foreign key from Location_Offers to Offer.

You can do the same on Location: make a compound key (Restaurant_ID, Location_ID) and use this as a foreign key from Locations_Offer to Location.

This ensures that any record in Locations_Offer that links a Location and an Offer, only links those that have a relation with the same Restaurant.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. In practice, I have some questions that come to my mind.  The table Location_Offers has three fields: restaurant_id, location_id, offer_id.  Do SQL databases allow for this weird relationship where the field restaurant_id of table Location_Offers will belong to both the foreign keys from the tables Restaurant and Offer?

Comment: I guess I will try to do it and discover how it goes.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes." A field can be at once a part of the PK of a table and also several FKs to different tables -- assuming that each definition is itself valid.